# JavaScript embed video that will change everyday

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I'm really  new to JavaScript so that I don't know how would I embed a video that will change every day. Example video 1 is for Monday and video 2 is for Tuesday something like that. I'd created something similar to this situation but for images only. Don't know how would I make it in video. Can anyone help me please?

**This is my sample approach in which images are changing depending on what date was set on your PC and its working really well.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title></title>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function(){chgDailyVideo();}
  function chgDailyVideo()
{
var vid_array = new Array();
vid_array[0] = "sundaypic.jpg"
vid_array[1] = "mondaypic.jpg"
vid_array[2] = "tuesdaypic.jpg"
vid_array[3] = "wednesdaypic.jpg"
vid_array[4] = "thursdaypic.jpg"
vid_array[5] = "fridaypic.jpg"
vid_array[6] = "saturdaypic.jpg"

var txt_array = new Array();
txt_array[0] = "Hi Im Sunday"
txt_array[1] = "Hi Im Monday"
txt_array[2] = "Hi Im Tuesday"
txt_array[3] = "Hi Im Wednesday"
txt_array[4] = "Hi Im Thursday"
txt_array[5] = "Hi Im Friday"
txt_array[6] = "Hi Im Saturday"

var d = new Date();
var i = d.getDay();

document.getElementById("dailyVid").src = vid_array[i];
document.getElementById("dailyTxt").innerHTML = txt_array[i];

}
</script>
<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
<p id = "dailyTxt">Hi I'm Sunday</p>
<img src = "sundaypic.jpg" alt"daily vid" title = "daily pic" id="dailyVid"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What specific problem do you have that is preventing you from employing this solution to videos? Post your *incorrect* video code so we can see what you're doing wrong, it's not much help to post *correct* code. :)

Comment: @Amadan Hello. Yieh I'm sorry my question is so confusing. As what i said I really don't know how would i make it in video. that's why i posted my currently approach using images. sorry.

Comment: Then your first step is to figure out how to put a video into a web page, making this question a bit premature. Kind of like asking for driving directions to a destination before you have a car available to you. Once you know how to put in a single video, it will be almost obvious how to adapt your image code to videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `<video>` tag instead of `<img>` and let the last two lines remain the same:

```
document.getElementById("dailyVid").src = vid_array[i];
document.getElementById("dailyTxt").innerHTML = txt_array[i]; 
// the above line will show up in case <video> isn't supported.
```

Note that you can only use videos ending with extensions ogg, mp4, etc and the above is the simplest form of how you could embed a video. See the link to know more about it.

[Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)